# What does tab completion in ipython or jupyter seek in order to suggest alternatives?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I am puzzled why this example:

```
import attr

@attr.s
class SomeClass(object):
    a_number = attr.ib(default=42)

b = SomeClass(7)
```

offers `a_number` as the only choice when `tab` is entered here:

```
b.<tab>
```

But in this example:

```
from attrdict import AttrDict
a = AttrDict(dict(a_number=7))  # Edited. was anumber originally
```

several choices are offered, but `a_number` is not one of them:

```
a.<tab>
```

Can the second example be altered in some way to allow `ipython` to show `a_number` as an attribute?

In each case, `a.a_number` and `b.a_number` evaluate to 7. So they each appear to behave as though they have an `a_number` attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ipython` does autocompletion by using a python builtin called `dir`. For an object, `dir` is meant to return the attributes of the object, of the class of the object and the of the classes bases. By default, it also excludes any entry in result of `dir(obj)` if it starts with an underscore unless you first typed an underscore. However, once you start messing with `__getattribute__` and `__getattr__`, `dir` may no longer find all valid attributes. This is because you are playing with the machinery with which Python fetches attributes and `dir` is not omniscient.

In your first example `anumber` is a attribute of the class and so is reported by `dir` normally.

In your second example you use `AttrDict`, and it *does* mess with `__getattr__`. In fact, it pretty much entirely delegates to `__getitem__`. Thus ,it appears that all your keys of your dict are also available as attributes. However, it doesn't implement `__dir__`, so the default implementation of `dir` doesn't realise that the keys of an `AttrDict` should be reported in the return value of `dir`. And thus, `ipython` doesn't know such attributes are available.

If you subclass `AttrDict` you could get autocompletion to work again. eg.

```
class MyAttrDict(AttrDict):
   def __dir__(self):
       super_dir = super().__dir__()
       string_keys = [key for key in self if type(key) is str]
       return super_dir + [key for key in string_keys if key not in super_dir]

>>> obj = MyAttrDict(something='value')
>>> obj.some<tab>
>>> obj.something
```

Comment: Nice! It does not work if the value associated with a key is a list of dict's, but your answer tells what I need to know.